# 8 handed play strategy

Tags: nlhe, poker-strategy

100 bb and everyone has about 18,000
Tournament

**Pre**
UTG, HJ, limp, BTN raises to $600, SB, UTG, HJ all call
Pot $2500

BTN has 8♥ 8⋄

**Flop**
8♠ K♣ 5⋄
Checks to BTN and bets $900 SB calls
Pot $4300

**Turn**
4♣
BTN $1400
SB $3400
Pot $11,100

**River**
J♣
SB $5500
BTN call
SB turns over 9♣ 6♣

What do you think of the play?

Comment: It is really unclear to me what is going on in this hand.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that SB (you) has 88 and button has 96s?

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans BTN has 88

Comment: I think you played the hand fine. I would bet much larger on the turn though. Easy GTO call on the river.

Comment: did not vtc, but perhaps throwing in an actual question could improve this.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Just trying to get some traffic on the site.  I thought review of the play was assumed.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but at least one person thought it was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I would kind of like to turn your question upside down and ask "What do you think about the villain's play?"

As far as your play goes pretty standard, nothing particularly wrong with it, generally that's the way it is going to go down, win or lose. I think many would agree and maybe throw in a little "Yeah, you just got unlucky".

But the villain's play: I see play like that a lot. That's people playing marginal hands for large raises pre-flop, with like in this case, pretty good results.

Blinds are a hundred everyone has 18k or so. Seems early in the tournament first or more likely second level or so. looks like a deep stack. Could you tell us a little more, lengths of rounds and your impression of the player? How far into the tournament you actually where?

I am thinking the villain was thinking that early in a tournament its worth taking shots for small amounts relative to stack size, to get the result this guy did, double up and bust or severely handicap a player. After all even though your raise was strong relative to the blinds, it really was not much compared to the stacks at the table. I find I just dribble off to many chips trying to "get lucky" but I am wondering if I have been missing something, did villain make a good play? Are the kind of results the villain achieved worth the risk taken?

Comment: Early, no real history.

Comment: Was it Deepstack?

Comment: Numbers are in the question.

Comment: You can analyze both.  It is a hand I saw on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I will not accept my own answer

**Pre**
Hero (BTN) makes a nice raise in my opinion.

**Flop**
Dry board
KK would have raised pre
Hero is very likely ahead a 
I like a small bet to keep a pair of kings around

**Turn**
I would bet more like 1/2 the pot for value
SB has indicated they like their hand. They could be on Ax or Qx clubs you need to charge.

**River**
Villain bets 1/2 the pot.  Hero is getting 3:1. Villain could think KJ, K4, or K5 is good. Villain could have hit a flush. But why raise the turn on a flush draw?  A busted straight draw could bluff here.  I call here.

**Post**
I just could not put villain on medium clubs.  They had a straight draw to keep them around and got runner runner. You kind of ran into the prefect storm. You could have bet more on flop but a set of eights usually holds up here.